# How to cast void* of an int to a float* so value is properly converted. W/O knowing about the type beforehand

Tags: c, floating-point, int, void-pointers

I have two values, one an int and one a float pointed to by void pointers (value1 and value2). They are received from a function call in any order. First the float then the int or vice versa. I would like to typecast the int to a float and then perform floating point math between them.

However if you were to typecast the int* to a float* then dereference it, you would get the bit pattern of the number interpreted as a float and it does not go through the int to float conversion.

So I was wondering if there was a clean way to cast one to the other without having to pass extra data about the types then doing a bunch of if statements.

For example

```
float x = -1.1;//types can be int on input
int y = 3;     //will be float if other is int
void* value1 = &x;
void* value2 = &y;
float z = 0;
void* token = &z;
*((float*)token) = *((float*)value1) - *((float*)value2); //but written to work
```

I want *((float*)token) to equal -4.1, but currently it would equal -1.1.

Comment: In which way did it fail to use the obvious `*((float*)token) = *((float*)value1) - *((int*)value2);` or the more explicit `*((float*)token) = *((float*)value1) - 1.0*(*((int*)value2));` ?

Comment: Is there any particular reason to pass those two numeric values as `void *`? Can't you declare a function  accepting two `float`s (or `double`s)?

Comment: You need to fix the problem at the point where the function is called. But you haven't shown the function call. See [mcve].

Comment: user3386109 Is on to something. Please explain how much and which influence you have on the source of those numbers. Can you make somehow sure that both void pointers actually do already point to floats?

Comment: I have no influence and they must be void pointers.

Comment: Please [edit] that info into your question. It might turn into a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/58281061/7733418

Comment: @user3386109  the function header is just 2 void pointers as parameters.

Comment: Please make a [mre] by editing your question. Also make sure that the MRE demonstrates all unknowns of your problem. I.e. call the function once with float, int and once with int, float, if that is the case. I assume that `token` is a parameter, too? The dupe seems more and more likely.

Comment: @Yunnosch you are right, it is a dupe. I couldn't find your answer when I was searching earlier.

Comment: With OP comment on my answer, I am now convinced that this is a duplicate. No problem. I only found it because I kind of happened to know. :-)

Comment: Are there restrictions on the ranges of the int and the float? For example, most practical, everyday integers have several leading zero bits. Their bit pattern as a float would be very small.

Comment: This is not a duplicate because there is a much better chance of their being usable restrictions that will allow a bit pattern to be classified.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan there was no restriction on input, well the restriction was INT_MAX and INT_MIN for ints ;/

Answer (score 0):

Don't cast. Convert.

```
*((float*)token) = *((float*)value1) - 1.0f*(*((int*)value2)); /* to be explicit about it */
```

or just trust the compiler to do math correctly

```
*((float*)token) = *((float*)value1) - *((int*)value2);
```

Apart from the fact that you need an actual place which `token` refers to.

```
anotherfloat = 0.0;
token = &anotherfloat;
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think you might answer "I don't kow which is the int and which the float." in that case allow me to refer to another answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58281061/7733418 (I might actually make that question a dupe-proposal in this case).

Comment: if that is the case, where there is not enough information. Then I will be forced to just pass extra information in ;( I was trying to avoid doing so.