# How to pass void pointer around correctly?

Tags: c

I want to return my struct pointer as a void pointer. In this function when I print the noOfTuples I correctly get zero.

```
typedef void* HashjoinDatabase;
HashjoinDatabase HashjoinAllocateDatabase(unsigned long totalNumberOfEdgesInTheEnd) {
  HashjoinDatabase db;
  
  struct database* d = malloc(sizeof(struct database));
  if(d == NULL) {
    puts("Some kind of malloc() error");
  }

  d->tuples = malloc(totalNumberOfEdgesInTheEnd * sizeof(struct tuple));
  if(d->tuples == NULL) {
    puts("Some kind of malloc() error");
  }

  d->noOfTuples = 0;
  db = &d;
  printf("Hello %i\n", d->noOfTuples);
  return db;
}
```

However when in main I cast the returned void pointer back to the struct pointer and try to get the same noOfTuples and I get large varying values with each run which I suspect are addresses

```
int main() {
  HashjoinDatabase testDB = HashjoinAllocateDatabase(10);
  int no = ((struct database*)testDB)->noOfTuples;
  printf("Hello %i", no);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hiding a struct behind a typedef is one thing, but hiding a *pointer* behind a typedef is a bad idea. Why not just write normal code and return proper pointers-to-types?

Comment: Your problem is you're retuning *the address of* the pointer `d` which is a local variable that goes out of scope when the function returns. You want `db = d` or just ` return d`.

Comment: "I want to return my struct pointer as a void pointer." Why? 9 times out of 10 this leads to the problem discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280538/how-to-verify-if-a-void-pointer-void-is-one-of-two-data-types/58281061#58281061

Comment: But really, learn about the difference between declarations and definitions and just return `struct database *`.

Comment: See this similar discussion: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294761/why-use-an-opaque-handle-that-requires-casting-in-a-public-api-rather-than-a-t

Comment: This is an assessed exercise, so the typedef actually came with the skeleton code

Comment: Find a better course then... :-D

Comment: Please direct your instructor here so that professionals may explain to him/her why their code is wrong. It is a horrible pattern that exists because some people don't understand the C language.

Comment: @IhowaOnaro [edit] and show the skeleton code.

Comment: Hiding a pointer behind a typedef is a bad idea, but hiding a `void*` behind a counter-intuitive name such as `HashjoinDatabase` is especially illogical.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct database* d = malloc(sizeof(struct database));
```

`d` is of type "pointer to `struct database`".

```
db = &d;
// ...
return db;
```

You are assigning to `db`, and returning, the **address** to "pointer to `struct database`".

```
int no = ((struct database*)testDB)->noOfTuples;
```

You are interpreting the **address** of "pointer to `struct database`" as "pointer to `struct database`", so `noOfTuples` is no such thing.

And that is why you should pass around "pointer to datatype", not "pointer to `void`" (and avoid casting), so the compiler can actually warn you if you get the types wrong. ;-)

Comment: And please, don't `typedef` pointer types. It leads to more confusion than it's worth...

Answer (score 1):

You're making things more complicated than they are.

You probably want this:

```
struct database* HashjoinAllocateDatabase(unsigned long totalNumberOfEdgesInTheEnd) {
  struct database* d = malloc(sizeof(struct database));
  if (d == NULL) {
    puts("Some kind of malloc() error");
    exit(1);
  }

  d->tuples = malloc(totalNumberOfEdgesInTheEnd * sizeof(struct tuple));
  if (d->tuples == NULL) {
    puts("Some kind of malloc() error");
    exit(1);
  }

  d->noOfTuples = 0;                    // why put this to 0 btw?
  printf("Hello %i\n", d->noOfTuples);  // shouldn't it be rather totalNumberOfEdgesInTheEnd ?
  return d;
}


int main() {
  struct database *testDB = HashjoinAllocateDatabase(10);
  int no = testDB->noOfTuples;
  printf("Hello %i", no);
  return 0;
}
```

There is no need for using `void*` here. Nor is there any need to hide a pointer type behind a typedef.