# Is it possible to have the same array of pointers to struct point to different types of struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm working with pointers to structs and have the following set up which has been working.

```
/* Initialized. */
struct base { ... };  
struct base **db;
db = malloc( base_max * sizeof *db );

/* When a new struct base is required. */
db[ i ] = malloc( sizeof( struct base ) );
```

Now, if possible, although not really essential, I'd like only `db[0]` to point to a different struct, `struct mem { ... }`.  Is this possible and what is the proper way to do so?

I figured I can set `db[0] = malloc( sizeof( struct mem ) )`; but `db` is already declared to point to a pointer pointing to a `struct base`; and the memory allocation of `db` is based on that also.

I'm confused because I read pointers must have a type or pointer arithmetic won't work properly; but I also read you don't have to cast the pointers from `malloc` even though it returns void pointers.

---

Regarding the duplicate question, although it discusses void type it doesn't answer my question of how to accomplish this or the risks of it. The comment by @4386427 appears to point to the real issue to be considered which isn't addressed in the other question or the one answer to this one. Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `db[0] = malloc( sizeof( struct mem));` It's legal.... Whether you'll get into problems depends on how you use `db[0]` later on. Since you didn't post that code, we can't tell

Comment: I believe that the question implicitly discusses pointers to void. If you do not agree let me know, but based on that assumption I propose the following duplicate:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to verify if a void pointer (void \*) is one of two data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280538/how-to-verify-if-a-void-pointer-void-is-one-of-two-data-types)

Comment: You could also use unions of the two types

Comment: @4386427 Thank you, that makes the  most sense. `db[i>0]` is a set of pointers to a sqlite database, a set of prepared statements, a char array of directory path, and then a regular int(no pointer).  `db[0]` is an in-memory database and has fewer prepared statements and no path. Probably best to just keep `db[0]` separate and out of the array of pointers and avoid risk of an unexpected error elsewhere. Out of curiosity, would `db[0] + sizeof(struct mem)` point to `db[1]`, and `db[1] + sizeof(struct base)` point to `db[2`], as can be done with character arrays? Thank you.

Comment: If you intend `db[n]` to be pointers to various unrelated structs, consider making `db` be `void**` so that it is less confusing to the reader

Comment: I meant *db[i], not db[i] since it points to a pointer.

Comment: @M.M Thank you. I thought about trying that before posting this question but couldn't figure out what to do with `struct base **db` . I get a bit confused because `db `points to a pointer to a `struct`. Can it be just `void** db` and then `malloc` will set the type when `db[i] = malloc( sizeof( struct ? ))`?

Comment: `malloc` doesn't set the type of anything; type is set by using the space .  Of course you also need some way of remembering or knowing what type of data you are storing in each allocation .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In majority of the architecture, the size of a pointer (to any type) is constant, and any pointer type will generally occupy the same amount of memory.

Unless you're on some really uncommon hardware/platform, you can assign `db[0]` with any pointer returned by `malloc()` using a different structure type used for sizing calculation altogether.

```
 db[0] = malloc( sizeof( struct mem ));
```

should do good, you just need to worry about memory leak, as you'll be overwriting the previous memory location returned by `malloc()`.

However, since you're storing a pointer to memory of a differnt type, while using `db[0]`, i.e., dereferencing it, you need to cast it to the proper pointer type (i.e., `struct mem*`) before you can use the pointer to access /operate based on the `struct mem` type.

That said,

> *I'm confused because I read pointers must have a type or pointer arithmetic won't work properly;*

That's true

> *but I also read you don't have to cast the pointers from malloc even though it returns void pointers.*

Also true, as when you assign the pointer to a variable of a certain type (other than `void`), the conversion is implicit. You can use that variable to perform pointer arithmetic.

Comment: `void *` can be converted to `struct foo *` on any platform.  Also the space allocated by `malloc` is untyped until first written .