# C function that can operate on either of two struct types

Tags: c, function, struct

So, I'm writing some code that does some linear algebra stuff using dynamic arrays, and I've got a problem. I need some functions to operate on both float_vectors and double_vectors, which are two structs that are defined like this:

```
struct float_vector{
  int size_cap;
  int current_size;
  
  float *data;
};

struct double_vector{
  int size_cap;
  int current_size;
  
  double *data;
};
```

One of the functions I want to use on both of these types is sum_vectors, which is defined like this:

```
int sum_vectors(struct double_vector *vector1, struct double_vector *vector2, struct double_vector *buffer){
  
  // Check if vectors, including buffer, are the same size
  if ((vector1->current_size != vector2->current_size)||(vector1->current_size != buffer->current_size)){
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Vectors and buffer are not the same size");
    return -1;
  }

  // Main loop and calculations
  for (int i = 0; i < vector1->current_size; i++){
    buffer->data[i] = vector1->data[i] + vector2->data[i];
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Is there any "good" way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

So, I thought of using _Generic, but I think it would be too hard to debug and that it would get really unreadable.

I also thought about using an union so that I can have only one "vector" struct, but I gave up on this because it wouldn't solve the problem of having to write two functions that do the same stuff.

EDIT:

As some commenters said, this might be an instance of an XY problem. As such, I will explain better how I got to this problem:

I'm writing some code to do some rendering in OpenGL in C. As such, I need some way of storing the coordinates of the vertices of the triangles I want to render. I already have a lot of code that uses these dynamic arrays (vectors and matrices), so I wanted to reuse the code.

Comment: Why you need `float` at all? For FPU on x86 this is slower type.

Comment: It's gonna be a mess ... `struct real_vector { int size_cap; int current_size; int selector; union { float *fdata; double *ddata }; };`. Use selector for `fdata` / `ddata`

Comment: It is for working with OpenGL, which uses floats.

Comment: OpenGL uses graphics card. So if you need do some operations on large vectors it would be better if you use video card too. Question is what are you doing exactly? After your last comment I smell [XY problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: Would it be an option to add another member to the struct which carries the information whether float or double? That is for cases where whatever creates the data knows what they are (usual case). Or add another parameter to the function which carries same information, for cases where there is no creator or the creastor does not know, but at point of calling the info is available (unusual, and usually the case where calling a dedicated float/double function is possible and better).

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280538/how-to-verify-if-a-void-pointer-void-is-one-of-two-data-types/58281061#58281061 I am not (yet) saying that it is a duplicate, but I suspect that it is so close that it either is one or is at least enlightening to you. I might set this as duplicate if there is no reasoned feedback to the contrary. Also, I am with Marek R, that this smells of a XY problem.

Comment: The OpenGL part of my code is for rendering a visualization of some trusses

Comment: The vectors are for storing the vertices of the triangles

Comment: Also, thanks for the answers. I think Yunnosch's comment with the link to another post here was really enlightening (I did not know anything about void pointers before), and I think that maybe void pointers might be the solution. But maybe it really is an XY problem, so I will edit my post right now to explain the problem better.

Comment: @MarekR: Not every aspect of graphics / OpenGL programming is well suited to be executed on the GPU. For setting up the 4×4 matrices that are used to represent geometrical transformations are more efficiently done on the CPU, and only the final 16× float32 values should be copied to some uniform buffer. Some newbies make the mistake of attempting to do *everything* on the GPU and then wonder about terrible performance, caused by introducing synchronizing dependencies. Rule of thumb: Only do it on the GPU if you touch >1k scalar values.

Comment: Why do you think `_Generic` would be unreadable or hard to debug? You just create functions `sum_vectors_float` and `sum_vectors_double`, and then wrap `_Generic` expression in `sum_vectors` macro. *(Assuming you want compile-time selection based on types. You didn't really specify if that is the case.)*

Comment: Well, having two functions that do the same thing would be bad because there would be two functions to debug instead of one.
I think that less functions is almost always better.

Comment: Because C doesn't have templates, you must always have 2 loops: one for float and one for double. It doesn't matter if you use `_Generic`, `void` pointers or `union`. Only option to avoid that is macro templates, but *those* are hard to read and debug. But your 2 functions are very simple; is it really worth it to try to avoid writing them separately?

Comment: See my answer: [Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621483/5382650)

Comment: "So, I thought of using `_Generic`, but I think it would be too hard to debug and that it would get really unreadable." I think not. There are some other more or less viable alternatives including polymorphism with base class + vtable (clunky) and misc other macro tricks including X-macro code generation etc (clunky _and_ hard to debug), or the old school void pointer + enum type tag (icky and rather unsafe). _Generic is less evil and can be combined with inheritance etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need some functions to operate on both float_vectors and double_vectors

Possible approaches:

1. Direct solution: Create pairs of functions: `sum_vectors_float(), sum_vectors_double()`.  To minimize the effort to debug/maintain nearly identical code, place them next to each other.
2. Like above, but also create `sum_vectors()` which employs `_Generic` to steer code selection.  This simplifies calling the functions.
3. This approach only makes sense if one has many identical functions that only differ in `struct` type.  Create 3 .c files: one with `int sum_vectors(FP *vector1, FP *vector2, FP *buffer)`.  2nd with `#define FP struct float_vector` `#define sum_vectors_float` that includes the first .c file.  3rd file with `#define FP struct double_vector` `#define sum_vectors_double` and includes the first.  Do not directly compile the first .c file.

---

Do not use the `void *` approach.  Defeating type is defeats the error resilient type checking.

---

- Research how `<tgmath.h>` performs a similar task.
- It appears to me that since the `float` routines and `double` routines are nearly identical, OP is looking for a way to not repeat function implementation source code.  Although that is admirable, a more important goal is to ease and improve user usage of these functions.  That is something OP has not discussed with code.

Comment: I'll do the (2) approach then, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of doing this in C even has an extra language feature: The *union*.

A union is syntactically the same as a struct, with the fundamental difference that at runtime, in a struct all members occupy separate memory areas, while in a union they will occupy the same memory area (so, *either/or*). So, you'll need an external marker to remember what type was stored in the union.

Your example could be implemented like so:

```
typedef union {
   int *int_data;
   float *float_data;
} float_or_int;

struct float_or_int_vector{
  int size_cap;
  int current_size;
  enum data_type { NONE = 0,
                   FLOAT,
                   INT,
  };

  float_or_int data;
};
```

Access to union members works just like access to struct members, but with prior consultation of the data type marker:

```
float *float_values = NULL;
int *int_values = NULL;

switch (vector.data_type) {
   case FLOAT:
      float_values = vector.data.float_data;
      break;
   case INT:
      int_values = vector.data.int_data;
      break;
   default:
      printf ("error, unknown data type");
      break;
}
```

Comment: In this case how would I access the data in the union? Would I access like "vector.data.float_data" or like "vector.data"?

Comment: Just like you access data in a struct, but with prior consultation of the data_type marker. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are really asking for are templates, which C doesn't have.

However you can imitate templates with preprocessor, and there is many ways to
do it, but it can easily turn into horrible mess. Least painful in my opinion is
to use `#include` method, rather than wrapping each function in macro.

**Warning:** While I've not had serious problems with tools (like debugger) with this method, it doesn't mean that you won't. Macros always add extra layer of abstraction which can be difficult for some tools to deal with (code completion for example).

**float_vector.h** - *Include this file in modules that call your vector functions.*

```
#ifndef FLOAT_VECTOR_H
#define FLOAT_VECTOR_H

// Template arguments here (only one in this example)
#define TPL_TYPE   float

// Run template
#include "template.h"

#endif
```

**float_vector.c** - *Compile this file.*

```
// Force function definitions to be included in next template instantiation
#define TPL_IMPLEMENT

// Run template with arguments from header
#include "float_vector.h"
```

**template.h** - *Actual code goes here.*

```
// Macros for concatenating tokens
#define TPL_CONCAT(a, b)    TPL_CONCAT2(a, b)
#define TPL_CONCAT2(a, b)   a ## _ ## b

// Name generation
#define TPL_VECTOR          TPL_CONCAT(TPL_TYPE, vector)
#define TPL_FUNCTION(name)  TPL_CONCAT(name, TPL_TYPE)


// Code that goes to header and source is below
struct TPL_VECTOR {
  int size_cap;
  int current_size;
  TPL_TYPE *data;
};
// Public function declarations for the header
int TPL_FUNCTION(sum_vectors)(struct TPL_VECTOR  *vector1, struct TPL_VECTOR *vector2, struct TPL_VECTOR *buffer);


// Below is code only for source file
#ifdef TPL_IMPLEMENT
// Function definitions
int TPL_FUNCTION(sum_vectors)(struct TPL_VECTOR  *vector1, struct TPL_VECTOR *vector2, struct TPL_VECTOR *buffer){
  // Implementation here
}
// Other functions here...
#undef TPL_IMPLEMENT
#endif


// Cleanup
#undef TPL_CONCAT
#undef TPL_CONCAT2
#undef TPL_VECTOR
#undef TPL_FUNCTION
```

For `double` you would implement `double_vector.*` files in same fashion.

**Note:** This method only works well when types are reasonably similar, like `float` and `double`. Also, if your template uses external resources that are type specific (like `pow`/`powf` functions), you may need to pass them using additional template arguments.