How to pass float value in void pointer function in C
I created a function taking void* and passed it a different type of value like float, int or double after that typecasting on that value in get_value function and action based on types.
Compiler error:

main.c:17:27: error: operand of type 'float' cannot be cast to a pointer type

Question
When using an int value, I can directly pass it with get_value((void *)10); and then access the data by casting back with (int). But float value gives the above compiler error. Why?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
void get_value(void* data)
{
    printf("Value %f \r\n", (float)data);
}


int main(void) {
    float di = 10.10;
    get_value((void *)di); 
    return 0;
}


What is your question? Do you have a problem with the code you show? Have you tried to build and run it? Please take some time to read the [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about how to write the "perfect" question, especially its checklist. And then [edit] your question to actually ask a question.

Amor, "like float, int and double" --> what do you want to happen when the bits of the type is more than the possible bits of a  void *? How about when the bits sizes are the same, yet certain void * combinations cannot legally be made?

I got that error.
main.c:11:36: error: pointer cannot be cast to type 'float'
printf("Value %f \r\n", (float)data);
^~~~
main.c:17:27: error: operand of type 'float' cannot be cast to a pointer type
event_process((void *)di);
^~
2 errors generated.

What are you really trying to do? What is your actual assignment or exercise? Please [edit] your question to copy-paste (as plain text) the full and complete assignment or exercise text.

@AmorWay, rather than using void *, using a wide type like uintmax_t is far less problematic.  Must the target type be void *?

And as a possible hint: What have your beginners material (books, tutorials, classes, etc.) told you about the dereference operator * and pointer-to operator &?

get_value(void* data) sounds like a function to save the gotten data at address data.   Not some function that take the pointer value and convert to another type.

I find your question unclear. I still suspect that this might be useful for you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58281061/7733418 I admit it is one of my answers. It is not necessarily a duplicate of this one, but it sheds some light where many misunderstandings exist, concerning void pointers, especially where they are function parameters.

This task sounds completely useless and wrong. If this is correctly quoted from a text book or course material, please consider to drop that. There might be some reason by a very small chance, but it shall be explained before you are tasked. Since you do not mention such, I'm afraid you are thought nonsense.

Your title asks "how...?" but the body only asks "why,?".  Which question are you expecting an answer to.

Why have you tagged this [embedded]?  Nothing about this question is specific to embedded systems code.

To answer the question why it works for int but not for floating point: the specific case of casting a floating point type to/from a pointer type is explicitly stated to be invalid C, simple as that.
C17 6.5.4 Cast operators:

Constraints
A pointer type shall not be converted to any floating type. A floating type shall not be converted to any pointer type.

Whereas C allows integers to get cast to/from object pointers, though doing so might be dangerous or non-portable, see for example C17 6.3.2.3:

An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.

Notably it is bad practice to cast int to/from void*. Usually when dealing with such conversions, you would use the integer type uintptr_t (stdint.h) which is guaranteed to be large enough for such conversions. And about the only time when you want to convert an integer to a pointer is when you want a pointer to a hardware address, so the pointer type would make more sense as volatile unsigned char* or similar.

You're question is not clear but if you're trying to pass a float value into your get_value function by typecasting it you need to pass a pointer into the function argument. Right now you're trying to change 10.10 into a void pointer which is not valid. You can try this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
void get_value(void* data)
{
    float *temp = (float *)data;
    printf("Value %f \r\n", *temp);
}


int main(void) {
    float num = 10.10f;
    float* di = &num;
    get_value((void *)di);
    return 0;
}
                                                                      


And that won't work because di doesn't point anywhere. Trying to dereference di will lead to undefined behavior.

Could you please run https://ide.judge0.com/

main.c:5:36: error: pointer cannot be cast to type 'float'

@AmorWay I have made changes to the code. Try with this.

Now it will work, but there's no need for either the di nor the temp variables. And you don't need to cast to void *, all pointers are implicitly comvertible to void *.

in int value i can direct passed  get_value((void *)10); and access (int) data.
But float value is not run. why?

@AmorWay Because that's the rules of C. It is possible, but it takes a few extra steps so it's not really worth it. Just pass a pointer using the pointer-to & operator.
